# Google Maps API results variables into php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I want to export search result variables (latitude and longtitude) from JS as the php variables. 
I know that it's necessary to have another php file, for example test.php.

variables below:

```
        marker.setPlace({
          placeId: place.place_id,
          location: results[0].geometry.location,

        });
        marker.setVisible(true);

        //infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
        //infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
        infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
            //results[0].formatted_address;
            results[0].geometry.location.lat(), 
            results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
            infowindow.open(map, marker); 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to create HTTP endpoint in PHP and then you can pass the lat lon to the url or can set into cookie and read it from PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) with [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) and JSON (for [js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) in order to pass data to your php file:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log (this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp?marker=" + JSON.stringify (marker) + "&infoWindow=" + JSON.stringify (infowindow), true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Then, in php:

```
$marker = json_decode ($_GET["marker"]);
$infoWindow = json_decode ($_GET["infoWindow"]);
// Do stuff...
```

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: Well, there is no errors in map file, but in index.php there are two errors: Notice: Undefined index: marker in C:\xampp\htdocs\licencjat\index.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: infoWindow in C:\xampp\htdocs\licencjat\index.php on line 21. I started session in the begining of the files, and of course xampp is on.

Comment: @jackson77, You probably do an error when you copy the example: you can put marke in your code at the place of marker, the system will crash. An other point, it is possible that the marker in your js code is not defined (like your infowindow) you may add this line of code in order to check if your js variables is defined: `if (!infowindow||!marker) {alert ("ERROR"); return;}`.